# Shopify Update Cart Total Price On The Fly

Tags: shopify

I am trying to update the cart total price on the fly. I have tried the shopify cart change or update processes but that seems to be not supporting the price update.
Any one knows any way of doing that ?

Any kind of help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to update the subtotals and total price in the cart is to change the quantity of a variant already in the cart. Remove one, you will obviously get a new price. Add one, you'll obviously get a new price. You can either do a conventional form submit to handle that, or use the Ajax API to change quantities, and then ask for the updated cart and manually update your pricing.

Comment: can we add quantities in fractional ??

Comment: Absolutely not. No cart works in fractions of a unit. You get to work in integer quantity only.

Comment: so how can I change a product price if a user wants to buy a product in meters and yard ex 0.25 or 0.50

Comment: Your price is always flexible. So you sell in unit prices. And you sell rounded units. So if someone needs 1.25 meters of material, you have to sell them 2 meters of material. Just round decimals up.